# Type of lambda with parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20, variadic-templates

Consider the following (https://godbolt.org/z/sfT3aesvK):

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct A { constexpr static int type = 0; };

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
int foo(Func func, Args&& ... args) {
    auto call_with_A = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
    std::vector<int(*)(Args&&...) /* what goes here? */> vec{{call_with_A}};
    int acc = 0;
    for (auto fn : vec) {
        acc += fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    return acc;
}

int bar() {
    return 1 + foo([]<typename T>(int a, int b) {
        return T::type + a + b;
    }, 2, 3);
}
```

The above does not compile, because

```
no known conversion from '(lambda at <source>:8:24)' to 'int (*)(int &&, int &&)' for 1st argument
```

My question is what the template type `T` so that `std::vector<T>` will accept `call_with_A` as an element?

I tried to print what `decltype(call_with_A)` is, but this seems to just be a `(lambda at [...])` expression for the compiler.

Comment: You can't convert a capturing lambda to a function pointer.  You can convert it to a `std::function`.

Comment: Does this apply even if the captured argument is constexpr? I'd like to evaluate everything in a constexpr setting, but then I cannot use `std::function` it seems.

Comment: It applies to all capturing lambdas.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code? Why do you have that `vector`? If you're really going to have multiple functions in that vector, then forwarding the arguments when calling the function is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a lambda expression is "unutterable". It cannot be written down directly. However, you can declare a `typedef` alias for the type:

```
auto call_with_A = /* lambda */;
using LambdaType = decltype(call_with_A);
std::vector<LambdaType> vec = {call_with_A};
```

You can also use class template argument deduction if you don't need to mention the type anyway:

```
auto call_with_A = /* lambda */;
std::vector vec = {call_with_A};
// the type of `vec` is `std::vector<decltype(call_with_A)>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Every lambda has a **different type** - even they have the same signature. Lambda functions that have identical body also have different type.

You can declare a `vector` of type using `decltype`. However, it is not useful. For example.

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
int foo(Func func, Args&& ... args) {
    auto call_with_A = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
    auto call_with_A1 = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
    auto call_with_A2 = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    std::vector<decltype(call_with_A)> vec;
    vec.push_back(call_with_A);
    vec.push_back(call_with_A1); // Not OK
    vec.push_back(call_with_A2); // Not OK
    
    return 0;
}
```

Your best option is to use `std::vector` of `std::function`. For example.

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
int foo(Func func, Args&& ... args) {
    auto call_with_A = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
    auto call_with_A1 = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
    auto call_with_A2 = [func](Args&& ... args) {
        return func.template operator()<A1>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };


    std::vector<std::function<int(Args...)>> vec;
    vec.push_back(call_with_A);
    vec.push_back(call_with_A1);
    vec.push_back(call_with_A2);
    
    return 0;
}
```